# Save function output to vector or column in data frame r

Tags: r, function, output

I am trying to write a function in R that 
1) loops through a column in my dataframe, 2) prints the content of that column and another column to the screen, 3) accepts user input on which content is acceptable and 4) either keeps content from columns 1 or 2 (if user decides it's correct) or saves the user's corrected input to a new column.

The last step of this task is where my function gets stuck and does not produce any output. The output column I am calling already exists in the data frame but the values just don't get assigned to it. If I am specifying a new column name for a new column to be created, that doesn't work either and I can't think of why.

I have tried assigning the user input to a vector (blabla) in an attempt to debug the code but not even that is working (regardless of whether that output object is created before calling the function but ideally, the output object should be created inside the function). When I run the for loop on its own with specific columns, it performs smoothly, so I don't know why it wouldn't in a more general function. What am I not seeing? It seems to be a problem with how I am trying to assign the output to a variable because printing it to the console as a final step in the loop works fine, meaning that the user input in step 3 did get processed correctly.

My function writing skills are not stellar yet, so I am open to suggestions on how to make this more elegant. I could obviously just use the for loop on its own to solve the problem since it works fine but I want to learn how to make a function perform the operation.

```
Check_Content <- function(data, contentcol1, contentcol2, outputcol) {

  #create output column:
  data[[outputcol]] <- c()

  for (i in 1:length(data[[contentcol1]])) {

  #show content of columns that are to be checked:
  print(c(data[[contentcol1]][i], data[[contentcol2]][i]))

  #request userinput:
  userinput <- readline("Type '1' for col1, '2' for col2 or correction: ")

     #keep content from col 1 or 3 or new content
     if (userinput == "1"){
     output <- data[[contentcol1]][i]
     } else if (userinput == "2"){
     output <- data[[contentcol2]][i]
     } else {
     output <- userinput
     }

  #save output in multiple ways but none of them works except print:
  data[[outputcol]][i] <- output   #this works if the for loop is run on its own
  data[[outputcol]][i] <- rbind(output)  #this works if the for loop is run on its own
  blabla[i] <- rbind(output)  
  print(output)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to put output column into list of arguments of your function. It is better revise your input arguments, e.g. it could be just contentcol1, contentcol2. If it is columns from one database , when you call function you have to specify in way you prefer, e.g data$contentcol1

```
  Check_Content <- function(contentcol1, contentcol2) {

    #create output column:
    outputcol <- c()

    for (i in 1:length(contentcol1)) {

      #show content of columns that are to be checked:
      print(c(contentcol1[i], contentcol2[i]))

      #request userinput:
      userinput <- readline("Type '1' for col1, '2' for col2 or correction: ")

      #keep content from col 1 or 3 or new content
      outputcol[i] <- ifelse (userinput == "1", contentcol1[i], ifelse(userinput == "2",contentcol2[i], userinput))
      }
    return(outputcol)
  }

  contentcol1 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1)
  contentcol2 <- c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)

 p <- Check_Content(contentcol1, contentcol2)
```